# replacing nan values with a function python

Tags: python-3.x, function, nan, data-cleaning

I have a big data set (100k+) with many more columns than in the snippet attached. I need to replace missing values with values from the reference table. I found countless articles of how to replace nan values with the same number but can't find relevant help to replace them with different values obtain from a function. My problem is that np.nan is not equal to np.nan so how can I make a comparison? I'm trying to say that if the value is null then replace it with the particular value from the reference table. I have found the way shown below but its a dangerous method as it replace it only as an exception so if anything goes wrong I wouldn't see it. Here is the snippet:

```
sampleData = {
    'BI Business Name' : ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'CCC','DDD','DDD'],
    'BId Postcode' : ['NW1 8NZ', 'NW1 8NZ', 'WC2N 4AA','WC2N 4AA', 'CV7 9JY', 'CV7 9JY',],
    'BI Website' : ['www@1', 'www@1', 'www@2', 'www@2','www@3', 'www@3'],
    'BI Telephone' : ['999', '999', '666', '001', np.nan, '12345']    
}
df = pd.DataFrame(sampleData)
df
```

and here is my method:

```
feature = 'BI Telephone'
df[[feature]] = df[[feature]].astype('string')

def missing_phone(row):
    try:
        old_value = row[feature]
        if old_value == 'NaN' or old_value == 'nan' or old_value == np.nan or old_value is None or 
old_value == '':                   
            reference_value = row[reference_column]     
            new_value = reference_table[reference_table[reference_column]==reference_value].iloc[0,0]    
            print('changed')
            return new_value
        else: 
            print('unchanged as value is not nan. The value is {}'.format(old_value))
            return old_value        
    except Exception as e:
        reference_value = row[reference_column]     
        new_value = reference_table[reference_table[reference_column]==reference_value].iloc[0,0]    
        print('exception')    
        return new_value
        
df[feature]=df.apply(missing_phone, axis=1)
df
```

If I don't change the data type to string then the nan is just unchanged. How can I fix it?